# Wordpress - Using post meta inside a plugin

Tags: php, plugins, wordpress

I am trying to use the function `get_post_meta` inside one of the plugins I am building but when I call the function it doesn't return anything. This page at the bottom mentions "Any Post Meta function can be used in WordPress template files." https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields

I want to know if there is anyway that I can use post meta inside the plugin.

Comment: get_post_meta() works well in plugins as well. Are you sure that your post meta exists and it's not empty?

Comment: can you show your code for `get_post_meta()`

Comment: Unless code is shown we can't do much so we can theorize that you are querying a `meta_key` that doesnt exist.

Comment: I think I got it working. I was calling the an ajax function in the plugin directly within the browser and did not return anything. But when I call the ajax function with javascript it did return what I expected. Its a little hard for me to explain all the parts. But thanks for all your support guys.